# How to validate text boxes with in a div javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, textbox

how do I integrate a type of validation in my JavaScript to the idea of If value of var firstName is = to null do NOT append the var sHtml and summaryHtml and change the class to change the textbox border and clear the field

rules:

```
firstName = must contain at least 1 letter and no more than 15 letters
lastName = must contain at least 1 letter and no more than 15 letters
jobTitle = must contain something other than an option value of "" (in the html option tag)
eSculation = must contain something other than an option value of "" (in the html option tag)
mobilePhone = must contain 9 numbers.  This field has a mask attached: (999) 999-99999
officePhone =  = must contain 9 numbers.  This field has a mask attached: (999) 999-99999
eMail = Must contain the following symbol: an @ sign and a . to represent xxx@xx.xxx
```

The JavaScript I am using to submit to a table is below:

```
newRow = 1;
currentRow = -1;

function CompanyContacts() {
var rowID = parseInt(document.getElementById("ContactsRowCount").value, 10);
rowID++;
if (currentRow > 0) {
    saveEdits();
} else {
    var firstName = $("#ccFirst").val();
    var lastName = $("#ccLast").val();
    var jobTitle = $("#ccjTitle").val();
    var eSculation = $("#ccEsculation").val();
    var mobilePhone = $("#ccMobile").val();
    var officePhone = $("#ccOffice").val();
    var eMail = $("#ccEmail").val();
    var sHtml = "<tr id='row" + rowID + "'>" +
        "<td class='tblStyle68wlb' id=\"ccFirst" + rowID + "\">" + firstName + "</td>" +
            "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + firstName + "\" name=\"cFirst" + rowID + "\" />" +
        "<td class='tblStyle68wl' id=\"ccLast" + rowID + "\">" + lastName + "</td>" +
            "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + lastName + "\" name=\"cLast" + rowID + "\" />" +
        "<td class='tblStyle68wlb' id=\"ccjTitle" + rowID + "\">" + jobTitle + "</td>" +
            "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + jobTitle + "\" name=\"cJobTitle" + rowID + "\" />" +
        "<td class='tblStyle68wl' id=\"ccEsculation" + rowID + "\">" + eSculation + "</td>" +
            "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + eSculation + "\" name=\"cContactPoint" + rowID + "\" />" +
        "<td class='tblStyle68wlb' id=\"ccMobile" + rowID + "\">" + mobilePhone + "</td>" +
            "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + mobilePhone + "\" name=\"cMobilePhone" + rowID + "\" />" +
        "<td class='tblStyle68wl' id=\"ccOffice" + rowID + "\">" + officePhone + "</td>" +
            "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + officePhone + "\" name=\"cOfficePhone" + rowID + "\" />" +
        "<td class='tblStyle68wlb' id=\"ccEmail" + rowID + "\">" + eMail + "</td>" +
            "<input type='hidden' value='" + eMail + "' name='cEmail" + rowID + "' />" +
        "<td class='tblStyle68wl' ><button type='button' class='XsmallButtons' onclick='editRow(" + rowID + ")'>Edit</button>" +
        "</td><td class='tblStyle68wlb' ><button type='button' class='XsmallButtons' onclick='deleteRow(" + rowID + ")'>Delete</button>" +
        "</td></tr>";
    var summaryHtml = "<tr id='SummaryRow" + rowID + "'>" +
        "<td id='ccFirst" + rowID + "'>" + firstName + "</td>" +
        "<td id='ccLast" + rowID + "'>" + lastName + "</td>" +
        "<td id='ccjTitle" + rowID + "'>" + jobTitle + "</td>" +
        "<td id='ccEsculation" + rowID + "'>" + eSculation + "</td>" +
        "<td id='ccMobile" + rowID + "'>" + mobilePhone + "</td>" +
        "<td id='ccOffice" + rowID + "'>" + officePhone + "</td>" +
        "<td id='ccEmail" + rowID + "'>" + eMail + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    $("#customerContactSubmitedTable").append(sHtml);
    $("#SummaryCCTable").append(summaryHtml);
    newRow++;
    document.getElementById("ContactsRowCount").value = rowID;
    $("#ccFirst,#ccLast,#ccjTitle,#ccEsculation,#ccMobile,#ccOffice,#ccEmail").val("");
}
}
function editRow(rowID) {
$('#ccFirst').val($('#ccFirst' + rowID).html());
$('#ccLast').val($('#ccLast' + rowID).html());
$('#ccjTitle').val($('#ccjTitle' + rowID).html());
$('#ccEsculation').val($('#ccEsculation' + rowID).html());
$('#ccMobile').val($('#ccMobile' + rowID).html());
$('#ccOffice').val($('#ccOffice' + rowID).html());
$('#ccEmail').val($('#ccEmail' + rowID).html());
currentRow = rowID;
}
function saveEdits() {
$('#ccFirst' + currentRow).html($('#ccFirst').val());
$('#ccLast' + currentRow).html($('#ccLast').val());
$('#ccjTitle' + currentRow).html($('#ccjTitle').val());
$('#ccEsculation' + currentRow).html($('#ccEsculation').val());
$('#ccMobile' + currentRow).html($('#ccMobile').val());
$('#ccOffice' + currentRow).html($('#ccOffice').val());
$('#ccEmail' + currentRow).html($('#ccEmail').val());
$("#ccFirst,#ccLast,#ccjTitle,#ccEsculation,#ccMobile,#ccOffice,#ccEmail").val("");
currentRow = -1;
}
function deleteRow(rowID) {
$('#row' + rowID).remove();
$('#SummaryRow' + rowID).remove();
var rowCount = parseInt(document.getElementById("ContactsRowCount").value, 10);
rowCount--;
document.getElementById("ContactsRowCount").value = rowCount;
}
function ccClear() {
$("#ccFirst,#ccLast,#ccjTitle,#ccEsculation,#ccMobile,#ccOffice,#ccEmail").val("");
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you need to validate `firstname, lastname, jobTitle, ....etc` before creating a new table row with these values?
if so... then what kind of validation you need and what is the rule for each field of those?

Comment: Correct about what is needed to be validated.  Rules:  firstName, lastName must contain letters, no other restrictions.   mobilePhone, officePhone must contain 10 numbers, I have a mask attached to show (999) 999-9999 and email must contain a @ symbol.  All fields must contain either letters or numbers.

Comment: OK, What i can advise is a validation jquery plugin, are you ok with that?

Comment: @MaveRick I am fine with jQuery, I am using this else where in my page.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `validation="regex here"` to the input tags first of all to give them an easy visual notification.  Beyond if you want to validate with jQuery, you can check each value and not send out an ajax request if any are invalid, using something like this to verify that ( string in this case ) values are correct `$(your_element_here).val().match(your_regex_here)`

Perhaps an `if ($(#id).val().match(some_verification_regex) == null){ return false }`

only letters: `/^[A-z]+$/`

phone number like you mentioned above: `/^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/`

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest is a validation `jQuery` plugin and you can find many of them and choose what suites your needs from bellow:

[jquery.bassistance](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

[ddarrenjQuery-Live-Form-Validation-For-Twitter-Bootstrap](https://github.com/ddarren/jQuery-Live-Form-Validation-For-Twitter-Bootstrap)

[jzae fferer-jquery-validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation)

Or you search on [jQuery.com](http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=form%20validation) site to get many jquery compatible validation plugins.

But if you don't want to use any plugin then you have to write your own validation code.

Email and other fields validation  functions:

```
function emailValidate(e){
        var p = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return p.test(e);
    }
function validate(val, min, max){
    return (val.length < min || val.length > max?false:true);
}
vfirstName = validate(firstName,1,15);//if between 1 and 15 will return true
vlastName = validate(lastName ,1,15);//if between 1 and 15 will return true
vjobTitle = validate(jobTitle ,1,50);//if between 1 and 15 will return true
veSculation = validate(eSculation ,1,50);//if between 1 and 15 will return true
vmobilePhone = validate(eSculation ,1,50);//if between 1 and 15 will return true
vofficePhone = validate(officePhone,12,12);//because `(999) 999-99999` length is 12
veMail = emailValidate(eMail);//also will return false if wrong email format
if(vfirstName && vlastName && vjobTitle && veSculation && vmobilePhone && vofficePhone && veMail)
    var errors = false;
else
    var errors = true;
```

Then before appending the generated row you can add some condition like:

```
if(!errors){
$("#customerContactSubmitedTable").append(sHtml);
//....rest of your code
}else
alert('please correct the fields');//or any other event
```

Comment: Both bassistance and jzae both seem to revolve around the form tag, I am using the form tag to submit my form but I also have this field of text boxes and drop downs to add multiple people via JavaScript and on the back-end code I am using C# to submit to the db.   I already have a whole form validation setup to ensure other text fields are filled out properly.

Comment: I guess I should change my question to how do I integrate a type of validation in my JavaScript to the idea of If value of var firstName is = to null do NOT append the var sHtml and summaryHtml and change the class to change the textbox border and clear the field.

Comment: Sorry dude i can't write the full code for you but i can inspire you with my answer to find a proper way to solve your issue and guide your imagination to generate a code suites your application.

Comment: I didn't see what you had going on above while I was typing, this gives me a great start, I never implied or asked you to write the code for me.

Comment: I know dude, just trying to help as much as i can ^_^